# How to extend the precision of mpreal precisely?

Tags: c++, gmp, mpfr

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpreal.h>
using namespace std;
using mpfr::mpreal;

mpreal x("1.001",64);
mpreal y("1.0",64);
y*=x;
cout<<y<<endl;  //1
y.set_prec(128);
cout<<y<<endl;  //2
```

The outputs are

1.001

1.00100000000000000002081668171172168513

I wish that the second output is something like

1.00100000000000000000000000000000000000

In fact, I've learned that one can replace

```
y.set_prec(128);
```

to

```
y=mpreal(y.toString(),128);
```

But this kind of conversion is time consuming.

Is there any better/faster method?

Thanks!

Comment: You already threw that precision away when you did `mpreal x("1.001",64);`. You can't get it back after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to setup precision globally, so that all `mpreal` variables will be created with such precision by default. Call the following function before creating any `mpreal` numbers:

```
mpfr::mpreal::set_default_prec(mpfr::digits2bits(N));

mpreal x("1.001");  // second argument is not required anymore
mpreal y("1.0");
...
```

where N is required precision in decimal digits.

Binary floating-point numbers don't give you actual decimal precision, it is only approximations to real numbers. More bits in representation = higher approximation accuracy. 
But some numbers can never be represented exactly in binary format. The 1.001 is one of them. So that you will always see non-zeros starting from some position in binary representation of 1.001 number.

Check [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://faculty.tarleton.edu/agapie/documents/cs_343_arch/papers/1991_Goldberg_FloatingPoint.pdf)  for more details.

Comment: Ok, setting the default precision is definitely the way to make the program run efficiently.  Thanks!